# Prestashop - noindex, nofollow in Multistore

Tags: prestashop, nofollow, noindex, multistore

I have shop on PrestaShop with Multistore function. I want add "noindex, nofollow" to one of my stores. I have main shop: eg. www.shop.com and second shop eg. www.shop.com/shop2. I want add "noindex, nofollow" only to "shop2".

Thanks for help!

Comment: What have you done so far to reach your goal? There is no such a button to press and get it. Please demonstrate your efforts.

Comment: Of course. I'm trying make it in {php} "if" instruction.

{php}
if (substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 0, 22) == "https://addres.pl/hurt") {
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow">;
       
         else             
            {<meta name="robots" content="index,follow">;}
 {/php}

But after that i have 500 Error.

Answer (score 1):

This code work's fine!

```html
{if strstr($smarty.server.REQUEST_URI, 'hurt') !== false} <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow"> {else} <meta name="robots" content="index,follow"> {/if}
```